# Clojure dothreads! function

Tags: clojure

I am reading Fogus' book on *Joy of Clojure* and in the parallel programming chapter I saw a function definition which surely want to illustrate something important but I can't find out what. Moreover, I can't see what is this function for - when I execute, it doesn't do anything:

```
(import '(java.util.concurrent Executors))
  (def *pool* (Executors/newFixedThreadPool
    (+ 2 (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)))))

(defn dothreads! [f & {thread-count :threads
                       exec-count :times
                       :or {thread-count 1 exec-count 1}}]
  (dotimes [t thread-count]
    (.submit *pool* #(dotimes [_ exec-count] (f)))))
```

I tried to run in this way:

```
(defn wait [] (Thread/sleep 1000))
(dothreads! wait :thread-count 10 :exec-count 10)
(dothreads! wait)
(dothreads! #(println "running"))
```

...but it returns nil. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, here's the same code, tweaked slightly so that the function passed to `dothreads!` gets passed the count of the inner `dotimes`.

```
(import 'java.util.concurrent.Executors)

(def ^:dynamic *pool* (Executors/newFixedThreadPool (+ 2 (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)))))

(defn dothreads! [f & {thread-count :threads
                       exec-count :times
                       :or {thread-count 1 exec-count 1}}]
  (dotimes [t thread-count]
    (.submit *pool* #(dotimes [c exec-count] (f c)))))

(defn hello [name]
  (println "Hello " name))
```

Try running it like this:

```
(dothreads! hello :threads 2 :times 4)
```

For me, it prints something to the effect of:

```
Hello  0
Hello  1
Hello  2
Hello  3
nil
user=> Hello  0
Hello  1
Hello  2
Hello  3
```

So, note one mistake you made when calling the function: you passed in *:thread-count* and *:exec-count* as the keys whereas those are actually the bindings in the destructuring that's happening inside `dothreads!`. The keywords are the words starting with a colon, `:threads` and `:times`.

As to what this code actually does:

1. It creates a new fixed size thread pool that will use at most the
   **number of cores in your machine + 2**. This pool is called `*pool*` and is created using the *Java Executor Framework*. See [1] for more details.
2. **The `dothreads!` function gets a function that will be called `exec-count` times on each of the `thread-count` threads.** So, in the example above, you can clearly see it being called 4 times per thread (`:threads` being 2 and `:times` being 4).
3. The reason why this function returns nil is that the function `dothreads!` doesn't return anything. The `submit` method of the thread pool returns void in Java and this means it returns nil in Clojure. If you were to add some other expression at the end of the function making it:

   ```
   (defn dothreads! [f & {thread-count :threads
                          exec-count :times
                          :or {thread-count 1 exec-count 1}}]
     (dotimes [t thread-count]
       (.submit *pool* #(dotimes [c exec-count] (f c))))
     (* thread-count exec-count))
   ```

It will return 8 for the example above (2 * 4). Only the last expression in the function is returned, so if in a function you were to write `(fn [x y] (+ x y) (* x y))` this will always return the product. The sum will be evaluated, but it will be for *nothing*. So, don't do this! If you want add more that one expression to a function, make sure that all but the last one have side effects, otherwise they'll be useless.

1. You might also notice that the order in which stuff is printed is asynchronous. So, on my machine, it says hello 4 times, then returns the result of the function and then says hello 4 other times. The order in which the functions are executed is undetermined between threads, however the hellos are sequential in each thread (there can never be a Hello 3 before a Hello 2). The reason for the sequentiality is that the function actually submitted to the thread pools is `#(dotimes [c exec-count] (f c))` and

[1] http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation! Actually, I have play a little with your code. At first time, it didn't print out anything in the cljr: [link](http://i44.tinypic.com/11io8pl.png)
But - strange enough - if I run the cljr from the command prompt (cmd) on Windows, it prints the messages right to the cmd window!
After that, I tried the whole thing with an anonymous function:
    (dothreads! #(println "Hello " name) :threads 2 :times 4)
...but it didn't work, which is strange too...

Comment: I think maybe the reason of the lack of printouts in the "cljr-without-cmd" mode is that the println function is compiled into some "System.out.println" call in Java (?), which wants to print right to some console output (?). By default, cljr somehow "catches" these println's while evaluating the source code, but when another Java threads executing the prints, these threads didn't know where to write their outputs...But this is speculation.

Comment: Totally speculating right now – but maybe try running the code using Clojure 1.3? That's what I tested it in. I don't know why it didn't print out anything in your example though.

Err, also if you accept my answer, please also tick it ;)

Comment: Any ideas why this is not working with an anonymous function argument?

Comment: This works: `(dothreads! #(println "Hello" %) :threads 2 :times 4)`. If you're trying to send it a function without any arguments in the code I wrote, I suspect it will just fail because the function doesn't have enough arguments. If however you make the submit line be something like: `(dothreads! #(println "Hello" %) :threads 2 :times 4)`, this `(dothreads! (fn [] (println "Hello")) :threads 2 :times 4)` prints 8 hellos as it should.

Answer (score 3):

It's used afterwards in the book to run test functions multiple times in multiple threads.  It doesn't illustrate anything by itself, but it's used to demonstrate locking, promises, and other parallel and concurrent stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`dotimes`, `dothreads!`, and `println` are not pure functions:  they're used to introduce side-effects.  For example,

```
user=> (println 3)
3
nil
```

That code snippet prints 3 to the screen, but returns nil.  Similarly, `dothreads!` is useful for its side-effects and not its return value.